# A function to reproduce the same number for each input

Tags: algorithm, math

say you have some data consisting of 2 columns and 1 billion rows, like:

```
0,0
1,0
2,3
3,2
etc
```

I want to create a function that will always give what's in column 2 if given an input from column one, so that it will be mapping values from column one to column two the same way it appeared in the data.

Column 1 is sequential from 0 to 1E9 (one billion)

Column 2 can ONLY be {0,1,2,3}

I don't want to just store the data in an array.. I want code that can calculate this map.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What language are you dealing with?

Comment: And how are then given?

Comment: I don't think it matters what language I use, but I'm using C#.

Comment: "I don't want to just store the data in an array.. I want code that can calculate this map." - What is the calculation?

Comment: I think I see what you are saying.  Given a map, you want to replace it with a function (that is not implemented with a map or any other data structure lookup).  Does the function only need to be defined over the domain of the given map?

Comment: yeah it should be defined for this domain and for this range.

Comment: is the data given before you come up with the function (that is, you have the data available now)? -- in that case we might need more information about the data. Or does the function need to read the data in some way?

Comment: If there is always 1000 rows, an array is your best option. Unless you want a formula for the sequence, in which case you need to define the sequence better (and in which case this question may be better suited over at [math.se]).

Comment: you could use a 999'th order polynomial, of course now you have 1000 coefficients to store, and evaluation would certainly be more costly than a table lookup..    If its about storage you could devise a scheme to store the data more compactly than standard integers since the range is only 5..

Comment: If it only contains 1000 rows, and column 1 is sequential and starts at 1, how can column 1 range from 1 to 1E9?  Either the number of rows is 1E9, or column 1 can only range from 1 to 1000.

Comment: I edited it sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

If the keys are dense, a 1d array should be fine where weights[key] = weight

Otherwise, a lookup structure such as a dictionary would work if the keys are sparse.

Not sure if you also needed help on the random part, but the cumulative sum and a rand(sum(weights)) will select randomly with a bias on numbers with larger weights.

edited for clarity weights is the array

Comment: hey, thanks for your answer, but I think you misunderstood me. I have edited the question.

Comment: what is the function? Maybe I don't understand how the data gets in and why an array won't work.    If you have the function can you calculate on the fly ex:     return f(input);   if it is data you receive, you could try to fit some model to it and later recreate from that model. More specifics would help :)

Comment: you just have some data like a map and you want to regenerate it without simply storing it

Comment: so you want to fit a model to the data then correct? and use this stored model to map between the domain / range so you won't need to store the full data set?

Comment: Then your solution will likely be highly dependent on the type of data that you would like to model :) I would recommend googling your domain for any existing solutions or toolkits that include modeling features.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming @munch1324 is correct, and the problem is:

Given a collection of 1000 data points, dynamically generate a function that matches the data set.

then yes, I think it is possible.  However, if your goal is for the function to be a more compact representation of the data collection, then I think you are out of luck.

Here are two possibilities:

[Piecewise-defined function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piecewise)

```
int function foo(int x)
{
  if (x==0) return 0;
  if (x==1) return 0;
  if (x==2) return 3;
  if (x==3) return 4;
  ...
}
```

[Polynomial interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation)

N data points can be fit to exactly match a N-1 degree polynomial.

Given the collection of 1000 data points, use your favorite method to solve for the 1000 coeffecients of a 999-degree polynomial.

Your resulting function would then be:

```
int[] c; // Array of 1000 polynomial coefficients that you solved for when given the data collection
...
int function foo(int x)
{
  return c[999]*x^999 + c[998]*x^998 + ... + c[1]*x + c[0];
}
```

This has obvious issues, because you have 1000 coefficients to store, and will have numerical issues raising x values to such high powers.

If you are looking for something a little more advanced, the [Lagrange polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial) will give you the polynomial of least degree that fits all of your data points.